# Reorder axis in TensorFlow Keras layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am building a model that applies a random shuffle to data along the first non batch axis, applies a series of Conv1Ds, then applies the inverse of the shuffle. Unfortunately the `tf.gather` layer messes up the batch dimension `None`, and i'm not sure why.

Below is an example of what happens.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

dim = 90
input_img = keras.Input(shape=(dim, 4))

# Get random shuffle order
order = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.random.shuffle(tf.range(x)))(dim)

# Apply shuffle
tensor = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather(x[0], tf.cast(x[1], tf.int32), axis=1,))(input_img, order)

model = keras.models.Model(
   inputs=[input_img],
   outputs=tensor,
)
```

Here the summary is as follows:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 90, 4)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_51 (Lambda)           (90, 90, 4)               0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Whereas I want the output shape of `lambda_51` to be `(None, 90, 4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap `input_img` and `order` into a list when you pass them to `tensor` layer.

In this way `tensor` layer becomes:

```
tensor = layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather(x[0], tf.cast(x[1], tf.int32), axis=1,))([input_img, order])
```

and your summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 90, 4)]           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_3 (Lambda)            (None, 90, 4)             0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
```